# Bootstrap modals not popping up after installing new libraries in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am working on an angular project in which I have used simple Bootstrap based modals. The pop ups were working fine but after using gridster and highcharts libraries in the project, the modals' pop ups are not working. I have also made versions of jquery,bootstrap,ngx-bootstrap similar and have compared the old and new codes with winmerge software but the code files are identical as well.

When I move to the previous commit, modals start working and when I move to latest commit, the issue appears again.

P.S: I know there should not be any issue by using gridster and highcharts libraries but there must be some conflict occurring due to which it is not working.

Please guide me as I am totally stuck and don't know how to resolve it! Below is the modal code I am using.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" (click)="populateModalData(row)"
    data-target="#configModal" style="font-size:10px"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</button>

<div id="configModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="classInfo"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content"> 
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="approveModalLabel">Modifica Gruppo</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table id="classTable" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead style="background: #E6E6E6">
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr><th>HANDLE</th><td colspan="2"><input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="modalData.handle"></td></tr>
              <tr><th>NOME</th><td colspan="2"><input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="modalData.name"></td></tr>
              <tr><th>STEP</th><td colspan="2"><input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="modalData.step"></td></tr>
              <tr><th>CONTRAENTE</th><td colspan="2">
                <select [(ngModel)]="modalData.category_id" class="form-control">
                  <option *ngFor="let obj of customersKP; index as i" [value]="obj.key">{{obj.value}}</option>
                </select>
              </td></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button (click)="updateConfig()" class="btn btn-success">Aggiorna</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what is 'not working'? Not showing a popup without any trace to console? look at the html code of the page after opening a popup, maybe there is just a conflict of CSS.

Comment: actually no error occurs on console. That's why it is more confusing. What type of css conflict?

Comment: css jf one library overrides css of another library and hides the popup

Comment: I have checked scss folder and changed styling according to previous code but still not working. Could you please guide me further about css jf one library?

Comment: sorry, I con't do it in comments on stackoverflow, so you will need to do it by yourself :) I can just suggest you not to look not in scss, but in final css and better in html code – dous something change there after you trying to open a popup